# Parameterized method types not working when within in a List

Tags: java

When compiling this code:

```
private BiConsumer<MyObject, List<? extends MyOtherObject>> setter;

<T extends MyOtherObject> void setObject(BiConsumer<MyObject, List<T>> container) {
    this.setter = setter;
}
```

I get "Cannot convert from BiConsumer <MyObject, List<T>> to BiConsumer<MyObject, List<? extends MyOtherObject>>"

Based on the parameterized method I assumed the types are compatable, as T can only be something that extends MyOtherObject.

The other reason I think the types are correct is if I remove the List it works.

I'm not sure what it is about introducing the list that causes this error.

Comment: T and ? are not the same. Both extends MyOtherObject but at the end they are not necessary the same. You need T in two case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a `List` which the generic is a upperbounded wildcard of`MyOtherObject` :

```
void setObject(BiConsumer<MyObject, List<? extends MyOtherObject>> container) {
    this.setter = container;
}
```

With the scoped method `T` you defined as `<T extends MyOtherObject>`, the `container` parameter will take the type of the received argument and `List<T>` can be a different type from  the `List<? extends MyOtherObject>` type.
For example it could be `List<MyOtherObject>` or `List<MyOtherObjectOtherSubclass>`. And the problem is that these cannot be assigned to  `List<? extends MyOtherObject>` defined inside `BiConsumer` : a generic type  variable.

You can check this behavior without using a method :

```
private BiConsumer<MyObject, List<? extends MyOtherObject>> setter;
...

BiConsumer<MyObject, List<? extends MyOtherObject>> listWildCard = ...;
this.setter = listWildCard; // compiles

BiConsumer<MyObject, List<MyOtherObject>> listSpecificType = ...;
this.setter = listSpecificType ; // doesn't compile
```

> The other reason I think the types are correct is if I remove the List
>   it works.

The error you encounter happens because your declared a generic type variable  that declares itself a generic type and that you try to parameterize the type of the inner generic type.  Making it is not valid because the parameter is so not a subtype of `BiConsumer<MyObject, List<? extends MyOtherObject>>` any longer.

With a simple `List` as parameter this code also would be fine :

```
private List<? extends MyOtherObject> setter;

<T extends MyOtherObject> void setObject(List<T> container) {
    this.setter = container;
}
```

Or by defining the whole parameter as a parameterized type, it would work too :

```
private List<? extends MyOtherObject> setter;

<T extends BiConsumer<MyObject, List<? extends MyOtherObject>>> void setObject(T container) {
    this.setter = container;
}
```

Comment: upvote for getting rid of the useless generic, I was too fast to answer

Comment: @Pedro Thanks for your fair play. If you know the number of too fast answers that I do ... :)  Parameterizing  a generic type included in a generic type is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the generic at class level:

```
public class YourClass<T extends MyOtherObject> {
  private BiConsumer<MyObject, List<T>> setter;

  void setObject(BiConsumer<MyObject, List<T>> container) {
      this.setter = container;
  }
}
```

Otherwise there is no relationship between the generic T of the method and the wildcard of setter. They both extend MyOtherObject but they could be entirely different classes, which is why it won't compile.